# JsonSerializer errors out deserializing dictionary of objects

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I'm having trouble deserializing a Json serialized dictionary of objects.

Here is some code to replicate the issue.

```
using System.Text.Json;

// my dictionary of objects
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dict.Add("test-date", DateTime.MaxValue);

// serialize the dictionary
var serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(dict);        // --> returns serialized = {"test-date":"9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999"}

// deserialize the dictionary
dict = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(serialized);

DateTime testDate = (DateTime)dict["test-date"];       // --> throws System.InvalidCastException - Specified cast is not valid.
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem and any possible workarounds for it?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint and inspect `dict` after deserialization, you'll remark that the value is not a DateTime but a JsonToken/JToken (or similar, didn't use System.Text.Json much). If all your Dictionary values are DateTime, deserialize directly into a `Dictionary<string, DateTime>` else, you'll need to check what the value is and deserialize on a case by case basis

Comment: Your target for deserializtion is Dictionary<string, **object** >. **object** doesn't tell the deserializer what type the respective json object/dictionary value(s) should be deserialized to (and neither does the json data itself contain such information). So, in absence of this knowledge, the deserializer deserializes such values simply as either some JsonElement instances or some JsonNode instances depending on the JsonUnknownTypeHandling setting.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace, I need it to be a dictionary of objects because it will contain a mix of no common type. How do I convert this `JsonElement` to the desired object type?

Comment: You have to do that in your code "manually". You (your code) will have to know somehow then what the desired data type for each of these dictionary elements/JsonElements is. The deserializer has no crystal ball to just know out of nothing what the desired data type is that you want...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement?view=net-6.0 Use one of the `(Try)Get` methods of the object, or the Deserialize extension method. But you still have to know the type

Comment: Perhaps look into using Json.Net/Newtonsoft.Json instead. Unlike System.Text.Json, it has the ability to preserve type information in the serialized json. However, keep in mind that such a thing is not a standard json feature and you might then be forced to use Json.Net/Newtonsoft.Json for both serialization and deserialization.

Comment: @PradeepKumar If you have absolutely no other choice, Newtonsoft.Json supports storing the type as Json Metadata : https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializetypenamehandling.htm and should be able to deserialize it as well

Comment: @Irwene, Thanks. `DateTime testDate = ((JsonElement)dict["test-date"]).GetDateTime();` worked perfectly OK. If you post your answer, I'll just mark it. :)

Comment: @PradeepKumar Accept Markus's then, he's suggesting just that and quite a bit more :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the JSON after the serialization, the `DateTime` is contained as a string (there is no data type for DateTimes in JSON). When deserializing to a `Dictionary<string, object>`, the `JsonSerializer` does not have any information on how the string that it reads should be interpreted (though a human most likely can see that it is a datetime value). Hence, it uses the generic type `JsonElement` to store the data. You cannot cast a `JsonElement` to a `DateTime` because there are different ways on how to interpret the data.

There are several ways to overcome this:

- If you know that all the values in the dictionary are `DateTime` values, change the type of the dictionary to `Dictionary<string, DateTime>`. Then the deserializer knows how to interpret the data.
- If this is not possible, you can try to implement a custom serializer that analyses the JSON and checks whether the value can be converted to a `DateTime`. However, if there are various types to consider, this might proove to be a tedious task.
- If you only need to check this at a single location, and if you know for sure that the value is a `DateTime`, you can use the following code to get a `DateTime`:

---

```
var jsonElement = (JsonElement)dict["test-date"];
var dt = jsonElement.GetDateTime();
```

Also, you could retrieve the value as a string and be more cautious when parsing:

```
var s = jsonElement.GetString();
if (DateTime.TryParse(s, out var dt2))
    // ...
```

See this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JPLl0F) to test.

Answer (score 0):

Just in one line

```
DateTime testDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dict["test-date"].ToString()); //9999-12-31 11:59:59 PM
```

or my usuall advise: Use Newtonsoft.Json and your life will be much easier.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

DateTime testDate = (DateTime) dict["test-date"];
```